# Calculating Total in gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a GridView with column Percentage. I want to get the total of Percentages in that colum. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 2):

[Here's](http://www.asp.net/Learn/data-access/tutorial-15-vb.aspx) the best tutorial for this by scott mitchell.

- http://static.asp.net/asp.net/images/dataaccess/15fig01vb.png

[alt text http://static.asp.net/asp.net/images/dataaccess/15fig01vb.png](http://static.asp.net/asp.net/images/dataaccess/15fig01vb.png)

some more references:

- http://aspalliance.com/782
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972833.aspx